# How do I set the working dir for C# MSTest Unittests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mstest

I'm using VS Code under Linux (Debian Buster) and currently write some unittests using the MSTest-framework. Some of my tests have to read files that I have stored in my Test-project NewAppTest. UnitTest1.cs needs to read some_data.json, directory structure:

```
NewAppTest
+ UnitTest1.cs
+ some_data.json
```

In UnitTest1.cs I use this code to read some_data.json:

```
[TestMethod]    
public void GetEmployee()
    {
      var data = File.ReadAllText("../../../some_data.json");
      Assert.IsNotNull(data);
    }
```

It bugs me that I need to prefix the filename with "../../../". Surely there must be a better way to set the current working dir. I googled some and found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1161084e-10f4-44fe-a017-8ce8f49cb9b9/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-when-running-unit-tests?forum=vsunittest) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN), but I don't understand it.

I would like to create a file like said .runsettings where I specify the current working directory for all my tests in the project.
I would rather not have to touch every testclass.

A sample minimal .runsettings befitting my use case would be nice.

Comment: You can use Resources for tests which is probably the better method. But you could probably also call GetExecutingAssembly

Answer (score 0):

A good way to include files in your test application is to use embedded resources. Embedded resources are bundled with the test build so they're independent of its location.
To embed a file, edit your `.csproj` file and add the following item group (as a child of `<Project>`):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="some_data.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(If `some_data.json` is in a subfolder within the project, the path would be `subfolder/some_data.json`).

To read an embedded resource, use [GetManifestResourceStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream):

```
var assembly = typeof(UnitTest1).Assembly; //Get the assembly in which the resources are embedded
using Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NewAppTest.some_data.json");

//Read the data from the stream as a string
using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this worked well. For all who are reading along:
I also created a subfolder named "subfolder" in the Test-Project and put some_data.json and more_data.json in there:

```
subfolder\
+ some_data.json
+ more_data.json
```

In the csproj I added this to include all files:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="subfolder/*.*" />
```

In the TestMethod I used this to read the files:

```
var assembly = typeof(UnitTest1).Assembly;
using Stream stream =  assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NewAppTest.subfolder.more_data.json");
```

This way you don't need to edit your csproj when you add new data files for your tests.